# SQL Display job code, job description and the number of employees holding each job

Tags: sql

Here's my sql query for my project, this is my first time doing a SQL course and I'm pretty much stuck.

```
--CREATE DATABASE constructCo; 
--use constructCo; 

CREATE TABLE PROJECT 
(
    PROJ_NUM varchar(3),
    PROJ_NAME varchar(25),
    PROJ_VALUE float(8),
    PROJ_BALANCE float(8)
);

INSERT INTO PROJECT VALUES('15','Evergreen','1453500','1002350');
INSERT INTO PROJECT VALUES('18','Amber Wave','3500500','2110346');
INSERT INTO PROJECT VALUES('22','Rolling Tide','805000','500345.2');
INSERT INTO PROJECT VALUES('25','Starflight','2650500','2309880');

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE 
(
    EMP_NUM varchar(3),
    EMP_LNAME varchar(15),
    EMP_FNAME varchar(15),
    EMP_INITIAL varchar(1),
    EMP_HIREDATE date,
    JOB_CODE varchar(3)
);

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES('101','Bay','Jackson','F','11/8/2000','502');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES('102','Senior','David','H','7/12/1989','501');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES('103','Arbough','June','E','12/1/1996','503');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES('104','Ramoras','Anne','K','11/15/1987','501');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES('105','Johnson','Alice','K','2/1/1993','502');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES('106','Smithfield','William','','6/22/2004','500');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES('107','Alonzo','Maria','D','10/10/1993','500');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES('108','Washington','Ralph','B','8/22/1991','501');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES('109','Smith','Larry','W','7/18/1997','501');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES('110','Olenko','Gerald','A','12/11/1995','505');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES('111','Wabash','Geoff','B','4/4/1991','506');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES('112','Smithson','Darlene','M','10/23/1994','507');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES('113','Joenbrood','Delbert','K','11/15/1996','508');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES('114','Jones','Annelise','','8/20/1993','508');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES('115','Bawangi','Travis','B','1/25/1992','501');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES('116','Pratt','Gerald','L','3/5/1997','510');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES('117','Williamson','Angie','H','6/19/1996','509');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES('118','Frommer','James','J','1/4/2005','510');

CREATE TABLE ASSIGNMENT 
(
    ASSIGN_NUM int,
    ASSIGN_DATE date,
    PROJ_NUM varchar(3),
    EMP_NUM varchar(3),
    ASSIGN_CHG_HR float(8),
    ASSIGN_HOURS float(8)
);

INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES('1001','3/22/2012','18','103','84.5','3.5');
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES('1002','3/22/2012','22','117','34.55','4.2');
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES('1003','3/22/2012','18','117','34.55','2');
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES('1004','3/22/2012','18','103','84.5','5.9');
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES('1005','3/22/2012','25','108','96.75','2.2');
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES('1006','3/22/2012','22','104','96.75','4.2');
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES('1007','3/22/2012','25','113','50.75','3.8');
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES('1008','3/22/2012','18','103','84.5','0.9');
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES('1009','3/23/2012','15','115','96.75','5.6');
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES('1010','3/23/2012','15','117','34.55','2.4');
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES('1011','3/23/2012','25','105','105','4.3');
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES('1012','3/23/2012','18','108','96.75','3.4');
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES('1013','3/23/2012','25','115','96.75','2');
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES('1014','3/23/2012','22','104','96.75','2.8');
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES('1015','3/23/2012','15','103','84.5','6.1');
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES('1016','3/23/2012','22','105','105','4.7');
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES('1017','3/23/2012','18','117','34.55','3.8');
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES('1018','3/23/2012','25','117','34.55','2.2');
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES('1019','3/24/2012','25','104','110.5','4.9');
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES('1020','3/24/2012','15','101','125','3.1');
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES('1021','3/24/2012','22','108','110.5','2.7');
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES('1022','3/24/2012','22','115','110.5','4.9');
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES('1023','3/24/2012','22','105','125','3.5');
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES('1024','3/24/2012','15','103','84.5','3.3');
INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENT VALUES('1025','3/24/2012','18','117','34.55','4.2');

CREATE TABLE EMP_CA 
(
    EMP_NUM varchar(3),
    EMP_LNAME varchar(15),
    EMP_FNAME varchar(15),
    EMP_INITIAL varchar(1),
    EMP_HIREDATE date,
    JOB_CODE varchar(3)
);

INSERT INTO EMP_CA VALUES('101','News','John','G','11/8/2000','502');
INSERT INTO EMP_CA VALUES('102','Senior','David','H','7/12/1989','501');
INSERT INTO EMP_CA VALUES('103','Arbough','June','E','12/1/1996','500');
INSERT INTO EMP_CA VALUES('104','Ramoras','Anne','K','11/15/1987','501');
INSERT INTO EMP_CA VALUES('106','Smithfield','William','','6/22/2004','500');
INSERT INTO EMP_CA VALUES('107','Alonzo','Maria','D','10/10/1993','500');
INSERT INTO EMP_CA VALUES('108','Washington','Ralph','B','8/22/1991','501');

CREATE TABLE EMP_US 
(
    EMP_NUM varchar(3),
    EMP_LNAME varchar(15),
    EMP_FNAME varchar(15),
    EMP_INITIAL varchar(1),
    EMP_HIREDATE date,
    JOB_CODE varchar(3)
);

INSERT INTO EMP_US VALUES('101','News','John','G','11/8/2000','502');
INSERT INTO EMP_US VALUES('103','Arbough','June','E','12/1/1996','500');
INSERT INTO EMP_US VALUES('105','Johnson','Alice','K','2/1/1993','502');
INSERT INTO EMP_US VALUES('107','Alonzo','Maria','D','10/10/1993','500');
INSERT INTO EMP_US VALUES('109','Smith','Larry','W','7/18/1997','501');

CREATE TABLE JOB 
(
    JOB_CODE varchar(3),
    JOB_DESCRIPTION varchar(25),
    JOB_CHG_HOUR float(8)
);

INSERT INTO JOB VALUES('500','Programmer','35.75');
INSERT INTO JOB VALUES('501','Systems Analyst','96.75');
INSERT INTO JOB VALUES('502','Database Designer','125');
INSERT INTO JOB VALUES('503','Electrical Engineer','84.5');
INSERT INTO JOB VALUES('504','Mechanical Engineer','67.9');
INSERT INTO JOB VALUES('505','Civil Engineer','55.78');
INSERT INTO JOB VALUES('506','Clerical Support','26.87');
INSERT INTO JOB VALUES('507','DSS Analyst','45.95');
INSERT INTO JOB VALUES('508','Applications Designer','48.1');
INSERT INTO JOB VALUES('509','Bio Technician','34.55');
INSERT INTO JOB VALUES('510','General Support','18.36');
```

The query I need to create is in the title as well but here it is "Display job code, job description and the number of employees holding each job."

I've tried some aggregate functions and subqueries like count and having but I just can't figure it out

If anyone can help I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. SQL Server and MySQL are completely different products. Uodate your tags appropriately with an [edit].

Comment: *"I've tried some aggregate functions and subqueries like count and having but I just can't figure it out"* What were those attempts? Include them in your question.

Comment: Provide the output which matches provided sample data. PS. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d483fdc3f0ab64d7eb500231342bb931

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you want, perhaps there is a better solution with fewer lines, but this can give you some ideas:

```
SELECT JOB_CODE, JOB_DESCRIPTION, COUNT(*) AS EmpCount FROM
(
    SELECT JOB.JOB_CODE, JOB_DESCRIPTION FROM EMPLOYEE
    JOIN JOB ON EMPLOYEE.JOB_CODE = JOB.JOB_CODE

    UNION ALL

    SELECT JOB.JOB_CODE, JOB_DESCRIPTION FROM EMP_CA 
    JOIN JOB ON EMP_CA.JOB_CODE = JOB.JOB_CODE

    UNION ALL

    SELECT JOB.JOB_CODE, JOB_DESCRIPTION FROM EMP_US
    JOIN JOB ON EMP_US.JOB_CODE = JOB.JOB_CODE
) x
GROUP BY JOB_CODE, JOB_DESCRIPTION
```